# How do I add a decimal to the code below

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to this, i have tried to add the decimal on the var var line 1.50 but it does not calculate correctly, can someone please help...Thank you...

```
if (fgh < 27) {
    total = 65;
} else if(fgh == 28) {
    total = 67;
} else {
    var val = 67 + (fgh.toFixed (0)  -  28) * 1.50;
    total = val.toFixed(0);
}
```

Comment: Please format your code so that it is readable

Comment: This isn't Java but rather JavaScript by the way

Comment: And I've tried to format your code for you and changed the question tag to [tag:javascript]

Comment: What is expected result?

Answer (score 0):

method: toFixed(decimal_digits), rounds-off the answer to 'decimal_digits'.

eg:

> var x = 5.95;
>
> x.toFixed(0);  // 6
>
> x.toFixed(1);  // 6.0
>
> x.toFixed(2);  // 5.95
>
> x.toFixed(3);  // 5.950

so, you should replace last line to:

> total = val.toFixed(1);
>
> // OR
>
> total = val.toFixed(2);